# Django: How to write current users name from every view (django)

Tags: django

I am writing small social application. One of the features is to write user name in the header of the site. So for example if I am logged in and my name is Oleg (username), then I should see:

> Hello, Oleg | Click to edit profile

Otherwise I should see something like:

> Hello Please sign-up or join

What I want is to show this on every page of my site. The obvious solution is to pass request.user object into every view of my site. But here http://www.willmer.com/kb/category/django/
I read that I can simply access request object from any template, just by enabling:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Not sure why but it actually didn't work :(

Maybe someone can help me and suggest a solution?

Thanks a lot,

Oleg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also note that you should use [django.core.context_processors.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-auth) instead of django.core.context_processors.request if you don't need the whole request context. Then you can simply type:

```
Hello {{ user.get_full_name }}
```

in your template.

Don't forget to pass `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` when you call `render_to_response` (or use [direct_to_template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template)).

Comment: Just a small note: generic views already have context_instance set, and therefore the {{ user }} variable is already available.

Answer (score 6):

There are probably two issues here.

Firstly, if you redefine `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` as you have done you will override the default, which is probably not a good idea. By default, the setting already includes the `auth` processor, which gives you a `user` variable anyway. If you definitely need the `request` as well you should do this (notice the `+=`):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Secondly, as described in the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) when using context processors you need to ensure that you are using a RequestContext in your template. If you're using `render_to_response` you should do it like this:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

from django.template import RequestContext

instead of

from django.template import Context

So now just call RequestContext(request, context)

More [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set up the context process, the request is passed to the template as a variable named `request`.  To access the user object *within* the variable you need to drill into it:

```
{{ request.user }}
```

Here is a [list of attributes stored in the Django Request object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).  More specifically, here is the [user attribute](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user).

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
<p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Would be enough if you have TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS already set.

Answer (score 0):

I think just by adding `locals()` can solve the problem.

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      my_data_dictionary,locals())
```